# How to load local geojson file and display it on leaflet map in asp.net mvc?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, model-view-controller, leaflet

I have a local geojson file saved in a folder. I would like to load and display the coordinates with marker on the map. I have successfully loaded the map on my html but i couldn't load the data to the map.

```
       var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([1.3521, 103.8198], 13);

        L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
            maxZoom: 18,
            id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
            tileSize: 512,
            zoomOffset: -1,
            accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoiaGlnaHBpZXMiLCJhIjoiY2p0Nml4NmR1MGhxajRhczA1NGFqZXV0NSJ9.c2tn1B3vCBSVni_W9dXQkQ'
        }).addTo(mymap);
        var hospitals = "~/Content/hospitals.geojson";
        var geojsonMarkerOptions = {
            radius: 8,
            fillColor: "#ff7800",
            color: "#000",
            weight: 1,
            opacity: 1,
            fillOpacity: 0.8
        };
        function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
            if (feature.properties && feature.properties.Description) {
                layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.Description);
            }
        }
        L.geoJSON(hospitals, {
            onEachFeature: onEachFeature
        }).addTo(map);
```

This is the error i recieved **Invalid GeoJSON object**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't load geojson files directly with `L.geoJSON`, you can use for this [Leaflet-Ajax](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax)

```
L.geoJson.ajax(hospitals, {
   onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Hello, i have try this but i got this error,
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () even though my url is correct

Comment: there is something wrong with the request. 404 means that a error happened on the server or the url can not be resolved. So take more time to investigate why 404 returns. Look also into the Network-Tab in the Developer Tools